# Trying to create a more clickable menu on mobile

Tags: css, shopify

I've been poking around, and managed to figured out the exact area of code which will give me, more or less, the results i'm looking for. But I realised that actually it breaks the website. I'll explain why!

So i want the menu of my ecommerce site to be more clickable on mobile. As it is, the menu is hard to hit with your finger, and more times that not it doesnt activate properly. So I found a way to make it more clickable by tweaking the code, but the problem i've just realised is it breaks other areas of the site. For example the 'searh' bar won't click, and the product image thumbnails will not go back to the first one. Something to do with the margin and area.

This is the old code which I have, which means that clickable area is too small:

```
#mobile-nav-return {
z-index: 7000;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 250ms;
```

The new code (which means the clickable area is pretty nice, but then messes up other elements on the site):

```
#mobile-nav-return {
z-index: 7000;
position: fixed;
top: -5px;
bottom: -5px;
left: -5x;
width: 24%;
height: -5px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 250ms;
```

Not really sure what to do. Probably there is a totally different way of doing it. I'm not so adept at this stuff, but i managed to get some results.. just seemed to mess up the rest of the page. Cheers

p.s. it seems the 'width 24%' part is the key, which expands the clickable area. I've tried making it smaller but doesn't really help things much either way.

Comment: it would be easier to help you if you post all of your code, the html as well..

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] of your problem. Without context, nobody can help. What you provided so far can be rendered in infinite ways depending on the rest of your code. You know you've added enough when the issue is reproduced here (use the snippet `<>` button). Ideally, you should have the knowledge to only add the relevant parts of code, or people will be deterred from trying to help, as it's too much to go through.